# Cloudfront stream only part of the video

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp

I'm using AWS Cloudfront RTMP protocol to stream my videos on website. In some cases I need  to present preview of video to my users. For example: I display only 60 seconds of 2 hour video and if user likes and buys it, then I give full video.

I know flash media server can do this, I wonder if it is possible to do it with Cloudfront.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, CloudFront does not support this functionality. You will need to point player to the different video in this case.

Comment: Any plans for future to support it?